# PyS60 : An always running app.. Hanging the Phones UI ? (How to tackle that ?)

Tags: python, pys60, here-api

I am testing my application in the Python Shell on Symbian S60 Platform.

Functionally, the application just runs great on the shell.. but its seems so hang the interface ?

**Even when : It does not include heavy processing !!**

The loop looks like :

```
while 1:
    // Application Functions called here.
    // Nothing processor intensive but has to run all the time.
   // It basically needs to track the phone and remain connected to the web over GPRS !
   time.sleep(5)
```

Suggest the way how the Quality Applications do it.. Because Quality matters !!

I have to proceed to the final application, but this way my simple application will kill the usability of the phone..

So, I am definitely doing something wrong ?
What is it.. Please Help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are preventing the process scheduler from switching to UI thread by calling the native python sleep. It doesn't do what you think it does on PyS60. You should use e32.ao_yield or e32.Ao_timer to manage application loop. RTFM carefully or you won't get any responsive UI.